# Explanation of a passage in Atiyah / Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, topological-groups

On page 105 the authors show that $\hat{\hat{G}} \cong \hat{G}$ (Proposition 10.5) and conclude that the canonical homomorphism $\phi : \hat{G} \to \hat{\hat{G}}$ is an isomorphism. How does the fact that $\hat{G}$ and $\hat{\hat{G}}$ are isomorphic imply that the particular map $\phi$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: I believe either they are being sloppy or it follows from the proof rather than the proposition itself.  I remember being confused by this when I did this chapter from the book.